# JOIN with a small table causes execution plan to change and query to slow dramatically

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-performance, index-tuning

I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE acl_sid (
 id bigserial not null primary key,
 principal boolean not null,
 sid varchar(100) not null,
 constraint unique_uk_1 unique(sid,principal) );

CREATE TABLE users(
 id NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('users_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
 email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    -- some ~10 columns omitted
 );

CREATE TABLE authorities (
 user_id NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL,
 sid_id  BIGINT         NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_users FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT fk_authorities_sids FOREIGN KEY (sid_id) REFERENCES acl_sid (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE );


CREATE SEQUENCE decidables_sequence START WITH 1 NO MAXVALUE;


CREATE TABLE decidables (
 id NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT NEXTVAL('decidables_sequence') PRIMARY KEY,
 assigned_to NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
 CONSTRAINT fk_decidables_assigned_to FOREIGN KEY (assigned_to) REFERENCES users (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL );

CREATE TABLE decidables_transactions (
 decidable_id NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 transaction_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL NULL,
 transaction_id VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 -- some 100 columns here
 CONSTRAINT uq_decidables_transactions_transaction_id UNIQUE (transaction_id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_decidables_transactions_decidable_id FOREIGN KEY (decidable_id) REFERENCES decidables (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE );

CREATE TABLE decidables_transactions_mv (
 decidable_id NUMERIC(20, 0) NOT NULL,
 transaction_date TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL NULL,
 -- some 10 columns here, excerpt from decidables_transactions
 assigned_to NUMERIC(20, 0) DEFAULT NULL NULL,
 CONSTRAINT fk_decidables_transactions_mv_decidable_id_idx FOREIGN KEY (decidable_id) REFERENCES decidables (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT fk_decidables_transactions_mv_assigned_to_idx FOREIGN KEY (assigned_to) REFERENCES users (id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL );

CREATE INDEX decidable_id_mv_idx ON decidables_transactions_mv (decidable_id);
-- few more indexes on omitted columns, that are not being used in the following queries
CREATE INDEX transaction_date_mv_idx ON decidables_transactions_mv (transaction_date, decidable_id);
```

I have this key set pagination query which performs quite well:

```
SELECT d.*,
       t.*,
       u.id    AS ass_to_id,
       u.email AS ass_to_email,
       NULL    AS ass_to_authority
FROM decidables d
         JOIN decidables_transactions t ON d.id = t.decidable_id
         LEFT JOIN users u ON d.assigned_to = u.id AND u.deleted_at IS NULL
         -- some more joins omitted for simplicity
         JOIN (SELECT t.decidable_id, t.transaction_date
               FROM decidables_transactions_mv t
               ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC, t.decidable_id DESC
               LIMIT 10) AS decidables_table ON d.id = decidables_table.decidable_id
ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC, t.decidable_id DESC;
```

But when I actually try to select authority of the user:

```
SELECT d.*,
       t.*,
       u.id  AS ass_to_id,
       u.email AS ass_to_email,
       s.sid AS ass_to_authority
FROM decidables d
         JOIN decidables_transactions t ON d.id = t.decidable_id
         LEFT JOIN users u ON d.assigned_to = u.id AND u.deleted_at IS NULL
         LEFT JOIN authorities a ON a.user_id = u.id
         LEFT JOIN acl_sid s ON a.sid_id = s.id
         -- some more joins omitted for simplicity
         JOIN (SELECT t.decidable_id, t.transaction_date
               FROM decidables_transactions_mv t
               ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC, t.decidable_id DESC
               LIMIT 10) AS decidables_table ON d.id = decidables_table.decidable_id
ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC, t.decidable_id DESC;
```

It starts to take minutes. I have ~10 rows in `users` ~10 rows in `acl_sid` and ~2 million in `decidables`, `decidables_transactions` and `decidables_transactions_mv`.

The execution plans are as follows:

- [Fast query](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/2135eh211679992d)
- [Slow query](https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/fd5da3924ad2ef9a)

Why does the query perform very different and slow down dramatically?

Comment: You should show the output of EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS), not just EXPLAIN.

Comment: I'm afraid I could not get a response from EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) under an hour on a 64 core production server.

Comment: If it just takes minutes to run the query directly, it should not take hours to run `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`.  Does it really only take minutes to run it directly, or does that too never finish?

Comment: What plan do you get for the slow query if you set enable_hashjoin to off?

Comment: @jjanes It never finished until I cancel, sorry for my misleading comment. Will try to set `enable_hashjoin` to off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LIMIT 10` is the key.

In the fast query, the engine starts by computing the `decidables_table` subquery with LIMIT 10, which returns just 10 decidables id. Then it joins all the other tables to this 10 rows, which is obviously fast.

When you add other LEFT JOINed tables in the slow query, the engine apparently doesn't see this opportunity and starts by joining the `decidables` table (with all its millions rows) with the other tables. Since those are LEFT JOINS, even if you only have 10 users the intermediate results will always carry all the millions decidables rows. Only at the near end the engine will join the limited subquery and drop everything but 10 rows.

How can you speed up the slow query?

ANALYZE could give some additional information to the query planner that could help choose the better plan.
You say that the bigger tables have 2m records, but the query planner estimates 12m records each, so statistics must be really off way.

But I suggest you rewrite your query, moving the subquery up the list to give a suggestion to the query planner to start by computing the subquery:

```
SELECT d.*,
       t.*,
       u.id  AS ass_to_id,
       u.email AS ass_to_email,
       s.sid AS ass_to_authority
FROM  (SELECT t.decidable_id, t.transaction_date
               FROM decidables_transactions_mv t
               ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC, t.decidable_id DESC
               LIMIT 10) AS decidables_table 
         JOIN decidables d ON d.id = decidables_table.decidable_id
         JOIN decidables_transactions t ON d.id = t.decidable_id
         LEFT JOIN users u ON d.assigned_to = u.id AND u.deleted_at IS NULL
         LEFT JOIN authorities a ON a.user_id = u.id
         LEFT JOIN acl_sid s ON a.sid_id = s.id
         -- some more joins omitted for simplicity
        
ORDER BY t.transaction_date DESC, t.decidable_id DESC;
```